# how to pass a json array from javascript to java?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json

I've read tenths of similar threads, but wasn't able to make my code work.
I wonder if someone could help.

What I need is to pass a json array from javascript to java via $http.get. On the java side, I'd like to parse it correctly.

I've tried many combination with JSONObject and JSONArray, but none worked.

Thanks for any help.

javascript code:

```
        vm.array1 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.InitArray.length; i++) {
            if (vm.InitArray[i].sel == 'S') {
                var string =  
                    vm.InitArray[i].agencyCode +';'+ 
                    vm.InitArray[i].duoDate+';'+
                    vm.InitArray[i].titleCode;
                vm.array1.push({myArray:string})
            }
        }
        vm.InitArrayJ = JSON.stringify(vm.InitArray);// converting to json array

        $http.get(PltConfig.baseAPIPath + '/v1/callResource', {
            params: {
                    array1: vm.array1
                }
        })
        .success(function (response) {
            ...
        });
```

java code:

```
@Name("CallResource")
@Path("/v1/callResource")
...
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + CHARSET_UTF_8)
public ServiceResponse< String > getBalance( @QueryParam("array1") List<String> array1 
        ) throws JSONException 
        {
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(array1);
    JSONArray jsonarray = jObject.getJSONArray("myArray");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? It could have something to do with the fact that array1 is a list of objects, not Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
public ServiceResponse< String > getBalance( @QueryParam("array1") List<String> array1 
    ) throws JSONException
```

to

```
public ServiceResponse< String > getBalance( @QueryParam("array1") List<HashMap<String, Object>> array1 
    ) throws JSONException
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to explicit where your response is, so try this

```
public ServiceResponse< String > getBalance( @QueryParam("array1") [FromBody]List<String> array1 
    ) throws JSONException
```

Or

```
public ServiceResponse< String > getBalance( @QueryParam("array1") [FromBody]dynamic array1 
    ) throws JSONException
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your line:

```
vm.InitArrayJ = JSON.stringify(vm.InitArray);// converting to json array
```

Is not doing what you describe in your comment, that converts a JSON object to string following the JSON notation.

Next:

```
   $http.get(PltConfig.baseAPIPath + '/v1/callResource', {
        params: {
                array1: vm.array1
            }
    })
```

You need to stringify the `vm.array1` you can't send the array object you need to convert it to a string using stringify and on your side, you need to convert the string to object.

Don't know why you are trying to send a JSON object in the query string, maybe you need to consider use POST instead to send JSON objects using POST method.